# generate viewmodel from model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, code-generation

I'm currently writing viewmodels for my (WPF/C#) app.

I have to do a lot of copy and paste though. Isn't there a way to generate the viewmodel from the model like generating the model from the database?

I haven't found anything about it on the net ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Karl Shifflet's [XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/). It's a Visual Studio plugin which includes various helpers for developing WPF or Silverlight applications. One of the features is exactly what you're looking for:

> - **Create ViewModel Class** - from a VB.NET or C# code window, easily create a ViewModel stub that includes commands and exposed data class.  Optionally you can elect to re-implement all Model properties on the ViewModel.

Comment: too bad - it doesn't seem to work with Visual C# Express 2008 =(

Answer (score 4):

Maybe have a look at [automapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper). This would at least save you from manually copying the properties between viewmodel and model.

Comment: I haven't checked automapper yet ... Does this work with C# Express?!