# Quick way to create/check Views against ViewModel properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a MVVM project where I'm using Caliburn.micro. The problem is that, I have my ViewModels in one folder and my Views in another. Also, I have about 20-30 properties per ViewModel and about a dozen ViewModels and growing. Is there any easy way to translate my string/int Properties to Textboxes and BindableCollections to ComboBoxes? In other words, is there any tool to generate a View automatically from ViewModel? If that is not possible, then is there any tool to check whether there is a control in the View that binds with a Property in the ViewModel? Frankly, creating Views by hand is quite tedious and is prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a duplicate of [generate viewmodel from model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577533/generate-viewmodel-from-model).

New link to the tool is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarlShifflettkdawg.XAMLPowerToysforVisualStudio2015.

Comment: The only qualm is that it doesn't follow Caliburn conventions of autobinding.

Comment: The guy seems to be pretty responsive in Q&A section, try to ask him if there is a workaround or maybe he will be willing to put a extra flag for that.